# CAFFE2 in COLAB

Tags: python

I have built caffe2 in colab using: `!apt install -y caffe-cuda`.
When I import caffe2 it imports normally, but when I import caffe it gives an error.

And when I do `caffe.set_mode_gpu()`, it gives me this error:

> ```
> File "demo.py", line 132, in <module>
>     caffe.set_mode_gpu()
> NameError: name 'caffe' is not defined
> ```